# Cypress.io - save value with JavaScript window.prompt

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, e2e-testing, cypress

I am new in Cypress and I have a problem.

I the app, I have a "Save Button". When you click the button, it is triggered JS `window.prompt()`. Inside the prompt you write the name of the save (like "Save from John") and click to "OK" - inside the prompt.

I need to cover this user story by the E2E test in Cypress.io.

Problem is, when I click the "Save button", cypress freeze in Click() event, when the prompt is displayed.

```
it('Make a new save with JS prompt', () => {
   cy.get('#save-changes-button')
   .should('be.visible')
   .click() //here the prompt is displayed, cypress stop and wait for click() event finish
})
```

May I ask for some help? I did not found siutable solution in Cypress.io Docs or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, fact is, the current version of the Cypress.io does not support interaction with `window` events. The way how to cheat it is the `cy.stub()` method.

This is my solution. The scenario:

1. Click the "Save Button" in GUI.
2. `window.prompt()` is opened.
3. Write the save name (like "Saved by Thomas") into the prompt.
4. Click "OK" in prompt and save the value.

And the code in Cypress:

```
    it('Save the value inside Prompt', () => {
            cy.window().then(win => {
                cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns('The value you write inside prompt')
                cy.get('#save-changes-in-gui-button').click();
                //... Saved value assert
            })
    })
```

Cypress by default change `window.pompt()` event by the stub and simulate click "OK". This solution works for me now. Hope, it could help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Side:**

```
<button id="createDirectory" (click)="createDirectory()">Create</button>
```

createDirectory() function prompts for directory name

**JAVASCRIPT Side:**

```
createDirectory() {
  const x = prompt('Enter directory name');
  console.log(x);
}
```

**How to achieve this in cypress ?**

```
it('Creating new directory level 1', () => {
    cy.window().then(win => {
        /* In case of writing something in prompt, use stub and then click on button on which prompt opens */
        cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns('level1');
        cy.get('button#createDirectory').click();
    });
});
```

- **level1:** string that we'll write in prompt box